# How to make java String class mutable?

Tags: java, compilation

I want to make `String` class mutable, simplest way to do this is make inner char array is public. How can i achive it?

Comment: That is completely impossible.  http://xyproblem.info

Comment: You can't make Java `String` mutable. Use `StringBuilder` if you want a mutable sequence of characters.

Comment: Yep, use [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) as @ElliottFrisch suggests.

Comment: You can get source code and change it. However, since all libraries assume that String is immutable, you also need to change and test them.

Comment: It's a violation of the Java license to distribute any libraries that include `java.` or `javax.` in the package name, or to distribute a version of Java that isn't compliant with the specification.

Comment: It's possible to alter private fields in a class (like `String`) using reflection, but it's also a bad idea (usually).  Specifically for `String` mutating the contents of the string will break a lot of code.  `StringBuilder` (as mentioned) is a much better idea.

Comment: I added another one answer to previous question about it.

Answer (score -2):

I'm pretty new to this so sorry if this is wrong.

Wouldn't it be possible to inherit from the String class then override the required method?

Adam

Comment: String class is final, impossible to inherit from it

Comment: Always check the documentation first: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html